# Clickable elements in SVG in HTML5 <picture> element

Tags: html, image, svg, anchor, aspect-ratio

I have a pair of SVG images in an HTML5 `<picture>` element, which are displayed according to the landscape or portrait orientation of the browser window. Like this:

```
<picture title="spong" />
    <source sizes="100%" srcset="spong-landscape.svg" media="(orientation:landscape)">
    <img width="100%" src="spong-portrait.svg">
</picture>
```

This works well. However, anchor elements in those SVG images do not respond to clicks when displayed in this way (in tested browsers: Firefox 60.0.1, Chrome 66.0.3359.181, Safari 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.4), all on macOS 10.13.4). They work fine if I view the SVG images directly in the browser.

Is there a simple way to tell the `<picture>` element to handle clicks according to the underlying `<source>` or `<img>`? If not, how can I display an image which (a) transforms with aspect ratio, and (b) contains links?

Comment: picture elements contents are not interactive. You can wrap the whole picture element in a link, but that's all.

Comment: Interesting. So maybe better to have an `<img>` and use JS to switch its src attribute as the aspect ratio changes? That's a shame, I was hoping to do it all in HTML.

Comment: why not just have the SVG inline?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The key properties I'm looking for are: (a) Two SVG images; (b) Which image displayed is chosen based on browser aspect ratio; (c) Containing anchor (href) elements.

How would inline SVG help?

For what it's worth, you can see the actual site at http://nickfest2018.com/

Comment: you'll need to write some logic to do that in javascript

Comment: Writing some JavaScript to achieve the image switching, I now find that SVG anchors in IMG elements don't work either. Sigh.

Comment: If you want to stay with external SVG files, use `<object>` or`<iframe>` tags, then the links will work. Remember you might have to use `href="..." target="_parent"` in the links.

Comment: I've resolved this by using two inline SVG images, and some JS called `onResize` and `onLoad` to set `.style.display` to either 'none' or 'initial'